# What is this ternary expression doing?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I have a function I'm testing that takes two arguments Definition and Element, and has a ternary statement in it that goes like

```
otherThingName: (_.has(Definition.thing, 'thingName') ? Element[Definition.thing.thingName] : null)
```

Now `Definition.thing.thingName` will exist, but Element does not have a property named Definition.

Is that property being set on Element while at the same setting `otherThingName`?

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: No. The bracket notation here works as a _getter_. If `Element` has that property, it's value is returned otherwise it returns an `undefined` value. Nothing fancy.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `Element` has a property named `Definition`. The square brace notation means it is looking for `Element.xyz` where `xyz` is the value contained in `Definition.thing.thingName`.

Comment: That was a weird typo, please refresh the page.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ternary expression is sort of a short hand if/else, so in the first instance, its testing the statement `(_.has(Definition.thing, 'thingName')`.

I don't work with underscore, but it looks like this test is checking if `Definition.thing` has a property of `thingName`.

If this comes back true, it will set `otherThingName` to be `Element[Definition.thing.thingName]`.

Otherwise it will set it to `null`.

`Element[Definition.thing.thingName]` is looking at an object called `Element`, and pulling back the property with the key matching the value of `Definition.thing.thingName`.

For example, if

`Definition.thing.thingName == "name"`,

`Element[Definition.thing.thingName] == Element["name"] == Element.name`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding out the text it becomes a bit more clear:

```
var str;

if (_.has(Definition.thing, 'thingName')) {
    str = Element[Definition.thing.thingName]
} else {
    str = null;
}

...
    otherThingName: str
```

It looks like it is defining the member of some object 'otherThingName' to be either whatever Element has set for field Definition.thing.thingName if that exists, or null otherwise.